# Rails Validation: Limit input to specific values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looking for "the Rails Way" to write a validation that limits acceptable input values to a predetermined list.

In my case, I want to only accept the values "-5", "-2", "+2", "+5", and nil. However, I think this is best as a general question: how do you predefine a list of acceptable entry values in a Rails model?

Thanks!

Comment: Great answers, thanks! I'm choosing Costa's because the answers are the same and Costa has about 2500 less reputation :) Cheers both.

Comment: I understand this was a while ago, but I would have recommended Beerlington's answer due to the inclusion of links and other valid suggestions. Quality is the decider we always want. :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

validates_inclusion_of should work.  For example:

```
  validates_inclusion_of :attr, :in => [-5, -2, 2, 5], :allow_nil => true
```

Answer (score 11):

You want to use [validates_inclusion_of](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_inclusion_of) with the `:in` and `:allow_nil` options.

```
validates_inclusion_of :field, :in => %w(-5 -2 2 5), :allow_nil => true
```

You'll probably also want to use in conjunction with [validates_numericality_of](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_numericality_of)

Answer (score 3):

## Rails 3+

The modern way to do this is the following:

```
validates :field, inclusion: { in: [ -5, -2, 2, 5 ], allow_blank: true, message: "not an allowable number." }
```